# UNITY - Instead of a script there is a blank notepad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

About five minutes ago everything was working fine, but after I restarted my pc, one of the scripts in unity stopped working. Other scripts can't access its methods anymore and when I try to open it, I just get a blank Windows Notepad. The assembly information is also blank. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: open Preferences >> External Tools >> External Script Editor , what do see out there

Comment: @MohamedAwad Visual Studio 2019 (Community). All the other scripts are just fine, it's only that one.

Comment: check if that one type is CS File

Comment: @MohamedAwad  Yeah, it is .cs

Comment: oh, that's weird, what about remove it and add a new one? reach to the file extension, open it with notepad, copy the script and add it to the new C# script

Comment: @MohamedAwad I would, but the notepad file is empty, there is no code. Looks like the script went completely corrupt

Comment: if it doesn't work with notepad, I don't think it's gonna work anymore, yes it's completely corrupt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure visual studio is installed, then in unity go to Edit>Preferences>External Tools and then change "External Script Editor" to visual studio.

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2019. For some reason, it's only that one script that isn't working, the rest is fine.

Comment: have you tried opening the script from visual studio instead?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Visual Studio remains black and a notepad file opens, also empty.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file in file explorer. There will be a temp file of the same name. It contains all your code. Open it and copy the code to the empty file and save it. You will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the guid of your .meta file changed. So unity is seeking for a file which seems to doesn't exists.

I had the same problem after renaming a script.
The .meta file associated with the script was renamed, normal, but also the guid changed.

So I had to copy past the old guid into the new meta file, and voilà!
Unity knows this script again.